# When I'm trying to append data-id; I got an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Check this out:
here's a simple code that works fine

**html**

```
<select></select>
<button id="btn1">click me</button>
```

**js**

```
$('#btn1').on('click',function(){
    var select = $('select');
    select.append($('<option>').val('v2').text('text2'));
});
```

When I'm trying to append data-id I got an error. Any help?

```
select.append($('<option>').val('v2').text('text2').data-id('id1'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/omarmakled/QQ44U/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this 2 ways

```
select.append($('<option>').val('v2').text('text2').attr('data-id','id1'));
```

or

```
select.append($('<option>').val('v2').text('text2').data('id', 'id1'));
```

http://api.jquery.com/data/
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 2):

First, `data-id` string is illegal identifier in JS (as it contains hyphen), therefore even if it were available as a jQuery object method, you should have called it like that...

```
someObj['data-id'](someId);
```

Apparently, that's too messy for such a simple operation. In fact, there's no such method defined in jQuery.prototype - which instead expects you to employ either `attr()` (to set *any* attribute explicitly), or `data()` (dataset API specific one).

As a sidenote, you don't have to make that many calls: this...

```
select.append($('<option>', {
  value: 'v2',
  text: 'text2',
  'data-id': 'id1'
}));
```

... is both more readable AND efficient. Note the quotation marks around 'data-id': object properties can be non-quoted only if they are proper JS identifiers.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WssCL/).

Answer (score 1):

The correct method to use is [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
select.append($('<option>').val('v2').text('text2').data('id','id1'));
```

Or if you want an actual attribute you can use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
select.append($('<option>').val('v2').text('text2').attr('data-id','id1'));
```